# API hosting in IIS is not working for a long time not requested until connected

Tags: iis, .net-core, configuration, scheduled-tasks, hangfire

I develop a web service (.net core) using Hangfire for running some background jobs as scheduled. This service was deployed in IIS and only have ONE responsibility for running schedule job based on the time (4 or 6 or 13 days) means that no accessible from requested outside.

Its working correct as the first deployment by trigger the feature job or set the short schedule job in next some minutes. But when service waiting for the next job about 4 days it it not working automatically until I connected to server for checking. Means that service was not running until someone connecting to.

I think there are a configuration value in IIS. There is a configuration value for timeout value or sleep time value for this service if have no requested to this service for a long time. Or some thing else ?

Comment: Microsoft expects you to use Worker Service and install as Windows service, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/net-core-workers-as-windows-services/

Answer (score 0):

You can build your Hangfire Server as a separate application (.Net Core) and run it from the command line, that way, it doesn't idle.